# Locking Critical C Program in RAM + Highest Scheduling Priority

Tags: c, memory-management, embedded, scheduling

I have a low level C program running on an embedded system that does critical system checks and runs the hardware (fans, temp checks etc).

It also pings /dev/watchdog by doing a simple fopen every few seconds as a last measure of defense to completely shutdown the system if this process stops running.

```
    watchdog = fopen("/dev/watchdog", "w");
    fprintf(watchdog, "1");
    fclose(watchdog);
```

Problem is this system is very limited on RAM, so a lot of the other process get swapped out to SD card which is very slow...sometimes these processes take over and can take serval 10s of seconds to completely before the watchdog process pings it again (its timeout is fixed at 16s by hardware).

I need to make sure this watchdog process is always in RAM (so fopen never pages to the SD card), and its scheduling priority is the highest possible with the CPU.

Im guessing I could run

```
mlockall(MCL_CURRENT|MCL_FUTURE);
```

to take care of the memory issue, and all memory in the process should stay in RAM. As for scheduling I have tried raising the process priority to -19 but that still does not keep it from making sure its executed every 5 seconds like it should be in the loop.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: "so a lot of the other process get swapped out to SD card which is very slow". How did you determine that this is the issue causing the "10s of seconds" of delay. I'm just asking because it's important to identify the real problem before diving in to working out a solution. For example, rather than jump straight to a solution of trying to pin particular processes it may be better to address or at least understand why some processes appear to be hogging the CPU. It's very unusual for the Linux kernel not to schedule a high priority process for that long. Apologies if you have considered already

Comment: This doesn't sound particularly low level at all. What system is it, more exactly?

Comment: Yes I already know whats going on an causing the issue, another lower priority program swaps out to SD card frequently, those SD card swaps cant take 10s of seconds to complete, so if this process has to open /dev/watchdog on the SD card it has to compete with the other swap operations which is where the stall is occurring. I need to make sure this process and/or the fopen/fprintf operation never goes to SD card and is always in memory. This is a debian system running 4.19 kernel on an embedded armv7 processor.

Comment: Sounds like you should simply disable swapping.  Swapping to an SD card is a particularly bad idea - very non-deterministic and subject to endurance failure.  The information about your platform needs to be in the question (edit it), not hidden in comments.  The real lesson here is that Linux is suitable for only a subset of embedded applications, and not well suited at all to real-time applications.  You can often do more, with less hardware without the encumbrance of Linux.

Comment: If I could disable swapping I obviously would. There is also a reason I dont need to get on here why this software will only run on a linux based embedded system. There are solutions to make low level software run near real-time on linux and never swap, those are the solutions im looking for not comments like "use different hardware or disable swap"